# Health care in Italy for the non-Italian spouse of an Italian citizen

Tags: italy, health-care, eu-spouses

Can the non-EU spouse of an Italian citizen claim a free health care if he lives in Italy?

Comment: (+1) Does the Italian citizen spouse live in Italy as well? My understanding (hopefully someone can confirm) is that the family of Italian residents is automatically covered by the statutory health system if they are themselves  covered but you don't get anything based only on citizenship.

Comment: Note that when it comes to Italian and non-EU citizens in Italy, the EU usually has nothing to do with it. It's only if one of the spouses was from *another* EU country that it would.

Answer (score 4):

Whoever is resident in Italy (foreigners from everywhere too) has the right to register to the National Health Care System. This registration is not just a right is even mandatory and is called "Registrazione Obbligatoria al Servizio Sanitario Nazionale".

Regularly resident is whoever has a valid permission (permesso di soggiorno o carta di soggiorno) or whoever is waiting for the renewal of a valid previous permession or whoever applied for the first time to have a permission.
In this last 2 cases is important to have the receipt that the request is done.

You (or who need to register) has to go to the closest ASL (Azienda Sanitaria Locale) from your current registered address (better if is the one written your residence document).

The document you need may vary according to your region/province/city but basically they are copies of:

Residence permission (or receipt of new/renew request) as stated above.

- A declaration written by you (autocertificazione) that state is your address (bringing any proof of address like rent contract, bill, house owner declaration that you have his permission to live in that house and anything similar could be helpful).
- Fiscal Code (you can also make a self-declaration if you know it)
- If you are still waiting for your residence permission some ASL are asking VISA and other docs too. Health Care in Italy is regionally managed so each region have fun adding or changing rules to complicate a bit citizen life. Not just to foreigner, but to everyone. Just smile and be patience.

More documents and proof about your resident situation are generally helpful in every office.

After you subscribe they will give you a receipt or a card that is the proof of your registration to the National Health Care Service (SSN: Servizio Sanitario Nazionale).

The foreigner will have the same rights of any other resident.
At this link you will find all the services you can claim and other useful information (is in Italian):

http://www.salute.gov.it/portale/temi/p2_6.jsp?lingua=italiano&id=2521&area=Assistenza%20sanitaria&menu=vuoto